# Cannot execute conda commands even though conda is installed

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I just installed the conda clean package and anaconda navigator.
When I use the command anaconda-navigator it says `command not found`
Same goes for anaconda-clean.

When I type in the respective installation commands the terminal says that requirements are already fulfilled.

OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating conda fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently installed Anaconda package then you need to add Anaconda to your PATH.
on your terminal type and see if you see the anaconda path. Generally on Ubuntu OS it automatically appends it to your bashrc or bash_profile in your home directory.

Check your path variable by

```
echo $PATH
```

Check your anaconda installation by

```
conda list
which -a anaconda
```

To see the contents of your bash profile go to your home directory on Ubuntu by

```
cd ~
ls -la
```

Now find your bash profile and open it by

```
more .bashrc
```

or
    more .bash_profile